# How to check if player clicked on a specific layer?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a mobile game with a simple mechanic where player must touch screen to jump. Problem is, if player clicks pause button, character jumps as well. I need to prevent this.

I came up with an idea of creating a square without sprite renderer and cover the area that I want to prevent from click and simply give a layer to that square so I can control if player is not clicking that layer, then jump.

How do I achieve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why not make a large invisible jump button?

Comment: Much better lol, thanks a lot.